# Random musical harmonies

Tags: code-golf, music

### The challenge.

Make a program that produces a random series of 8 notes in the scale of E minor, and then harmonizes them.

### Details.

- Notes must be represented in output as a 1-2 char string, which designates the note and if it is sharped or not, followed by a number, which designates the octave. Examples would be `C3`, `D#7`, or `A#1`. No notes can be flatted, only sharped.
- No notes can have an octave lower than `1`.
- The scale starts at `E4` and ends at `D5`. No notes that are randomly generated can be outside of these bounds, but the chords can be below it.
- Each note that the program randomly makes must have a chord of three notes an octave below it.
- The three notes of a chord are as followed:

  - Root note: The note originally randomly generated, but an octave lower.
  - Middle note: Depending on what note fits within the scale, this is `3` to `4` semitones above the root note and is what makes a chord major or minor.
  - Top note: The fifth of the root note, or raised `7` semitones. If the fifth of the root note isn't in the scale, then the top note is `6` semitones above the root.
- Output is simply just a print to the console of a string.

### Output.

What a note and its harmony look like:
`({E4}, {E3}, {G3}, {B3})`
Output format:
`[ (*note and harmony*), x8 ]`
All space padding is optional.

## Conclusion.

Any languages are allowed, and the shortest response, in bytes, after a week is the winner.

Comment: When you say random you should specify a distribution.  Many things are random or may appear random,  we can't tell which of these you actually want.  I would also question what adding randomness to this challenge actually does to improve it.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC. There are a number of things that are unclear. The scale of E natural minor  is  `E F# G A B C D` and you mention that the scale ends on D. But then you also mention `D#` and `A#` . As far as I'm aware `A#` is not a note in any version of E minor. `D#` instead of D occurs in some variants of the E minor scale, but in harmonies it would typically only be used to substitute a B minor chord `B D F#` with a B major chord `B D# F#` and never as the root note of a chord so I'm wondering why it's included. I suggest you just list the 7 possible outputs, one for each note of the scale

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I was using those as references, not as if they were part of the scale

Comment: Well, you got some upvotes, because there is the kernel of a good idea in here. But you will need to make the challenge clearer to get it reopened. Consider my and Ad Hoc's comments. Writing a good challenge is hard and you can post to the sandbox first to get feedback on your challenge - see the box at top right of the screen. I'd also recommend that you answer a few challenges to find out what we're about.

Comment: If I've understood correctly the required outputs are `[E4 E3 G3 B3]` `[F#4 F#3 A3 C4]` `[G4 G3 B3 D4]` `[A4 A3 C4 E4]` `[B4 B3 D4 F#4]` `[C5 C4 E4 G4]` `[D5 D4 F#4 A4 ]` is that correct? if so edit it into the question.

Comment: If you do edit the challenge, I suggest thinking about whether you can make it more approachable for those without any background in music. LevelRiverSt's comments are a good start.